# Possible to make MySQL ignore joins under certain conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, join

The following code successfully gives me details of logged in peoples' requested books, and the books themselves, from a specific library.

```
SELECT bookRequest.version, bookRequest.status, users.user_id, users.firstname, users.lastname, books.Author, books.Title
FROM users 
INNER JOIN bookRequest
ON users.user_id=bookRequest.user_id 
INNER JOIN books
ON bookRequest.bookID = books.ID
INNER JOIN libraryTokens
ON bookRequest.libraryID = libraryTokens.libraryID
WHERE libraryTokens.libraryID='". $libraryID ."'
```

The bookRequest table also has columns for directly storing manually added requests for books not in the system, requested by people not logged in. In this case, bookRequest.user_id is always -1, and the extra columns bookRequest.firstname, bookRequest.lastname, bookRequest.Author, and bookRequest.Title hold the guest's name and their non-listed book request's details.

I'm trying to figure out a way (I have no idea if it's even possible) of, when retrieving a library's book requests, ignoring the

```
INNER JOIN bookRequest
ON users.user_id=bookRequest.user_id 
INNER JOIN books
ON bookRequest.bookID = books.ID
```

part of the query if bookRequest.user_id is -1, and instead retrieving bookRequest.firstname, bookRequest.lastname, bookRequest.Author, and bookRequest.Title, but not ignoring the joins if bookRequest.user_id>-1?

Is it possible, or wayyyyy too messy, and instead I should do two separate queries, and combine the resulting arrays using php?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: it can not be done in JOIN however while selecting the data you can use case-when to specify what to be selected when and finally give an alias name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your `JOIN` to an `OUTER JOIN` and add a `CASE` statement to your query.  Something like this:

```
SELECT bookRequest.version, 
       bookRequest.status, 
       CASE WHEN bookRequest.user_id = -1 THEN bookRequest.user_id ELSE users.user_id END userid, 
       CASE WHEN bookRequest.user_id = -1 THEN bookRequest.firstname ELSE users.firstname END firstname, 
       ...
FROM bookRequest 
    JOIN libraryTokens
        ON bookRequest.libraryID = libraryTokens.libraryID
    LEFT JOIN books
        ON bookRequest.bookID = books.ID
    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON users.user_id=bookRequest.user_id 
WHERE libraryTokens.libraryID='". $libraryID ."'
```

Comment: I would use an `IF()` instead of a `CASE`, but this should do it.